# HtmlElementCollection in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I’m having problems changing one line of code from an IE web browser to a CefSharp browser using C#. 
The line that works in IE is.

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

In CefSharp I’ve tried.

```
private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e) 
{
   if (sender == CurBrowser) 
   {
    if (e.IsLoading) 
{
    } 
else 
{
    string UserNameAttributesFile = @"C:\Users\???\OneDrive\Documents\UserID.txt";
var userNameAttributes = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(UserNameAttributesFile),        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    string passwordAttributesFile = @"C:\Users\???\OneDrive\Documents\Pass.txt";
var passwordAttributes = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(passwordAttributesFile), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    string sendAttributesFile = @"C:\Users\???\OneDrive\Documents\ButtonSend.txt";
var sendAttributes = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(sendAttributesFile), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

HtmlElementCollection elements = CurBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('input')"); 

        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (userNameAttributes.Contains(element.Name))
            {
               element.SetAttribute("value", Program.NameID);
            }

            if (passwordAttributes.Contains(element.Name))
            {
               element.SetAttribute("value", Program.NamePw);
            }

            if (sendAttributes.Contains(element.Name))
            {
               element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Those are just a few of the versions I’ve tried. Also tried Googling with no help.
That line proceeds a foreach statement that cycles through the web page to find the username and password boxes and inputting to them.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result you will have to rewrite your code to use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But being only an entry-level C# person and your reference is for advance level I don’t comprehend that article. I can get the browser to work by using this     CurBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById(" + '\'' + Program.NameID + '\''+   ").value=" + '\'' + Program.user + '\'');  But that requires updating the database with all of that data. I already have that data in text documents which I hashed into the IE version of the program. That is why I was hoping to do the same In the Chromium version.

Comment: I thought only that one line needed changing but if do I need to change the whole thing I would like to see an article that explains or shows ‘how-to’ in a much simpler way.

Comment: What gave you the impression you only needed to change one line? You can self answer this question providing a `how-to`, I can then include it as part of the official documentation.

Comment: The only thing different between the IE version and CefSharp version is that line. In IE it works. Because of that line I can't start testing to see if any other lines need changing. Everything after the = sign in HtmlElementCollection elements is underlined. I get           Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units. To browse the NET. Framework source code for this type, see the Reference source. 
Cannot implicitly convert type ‘void to ‘System.Windows.Form.HtmlElement.Collection’
I don't know if could be a syntax, punctuation or bracketing problem.

Comment: I remember when using the same code between vb6, vb.net and vba you always had a slight difference with the syntax or bracketing.

Comment: You **cannot** use `HtmlElementCollection` with `CefSharp`. Also the `ExecuteScriptAsync` method is for simply executing script, it does not return a result. You need to use `EvaluateScriptAsync` if you wish to return a result. You'll have to rewrite your code to use javascript. You can use `Chrome DevTools` for debugging see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging 
If this doesn't work for you then you'll need to look at using a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use `HtmlElementCollection` with `CefSharp`.

To modify the `DOM` you can execute `JavasScript`. To fill our a form you can use something like the following:

```
//Build up some javaScript
//Dynamically generate your script as required.
var javaScript = @"(function(){
  document.getElementById('email').value='me@me.org';
  document.getElementById('pass').value='Password123';
  //Submit form, you can just as easily click a button
  document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
})();";
```

```cs
//The page must be loaded for this to work
//Use this if the page is already loaded.
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(javaScript);

//Use this helper method to execute when the page loads
//Only execute on single page load
browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(javaScript, oneTime:true);
```

For reference:

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript